# Print HTML pages which contain tables using JAVA

Tags: java, printing, ip

I want to print HTML pages by JAVA. The pages contain table, I want to print the pages exactly as HTML pages displayed.

- Currently, I am able to print out the words in this HTML page. However, it can't print out the physical table layout, like the borders. 

- In addition, I want to use **printer IP** (eg.10.10.130.212:myPrinter) to connect with printer. Currently I am connecting to my default printer. I don't know how to do this part.

my code:

```
    JEditorPane html = new JEditorPane();
    html.setContentType("text/html");

    try {
        html.read(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Documents and Settings/attlhn1/Desktop/WO-2449682.html")), "");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void print(HTMLDocument htmlDocument) { 
        setDocument(htmlDocument); 
        printDialog(); 
    }

    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) html.getDocument();
    print(doc);
```

HTML sample, besides the content, i want to print out the tables as well

```
<table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2 style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>
<tr>
 <td>S/No</td>
 <td>Stock Code</td>
 <td>Condition Code</td>
 <td width=200>Description</td>
 <td>Unit Cost</td>
 <td width=50>Current Balance</td>
 <td>Bin Locn</td>
 <td>Lot No</td>
 <td width=50>Quantity Requested</td>
 <td width=200>Remarks</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign=top>1</td>
 <td valign=top>0110002</td>
 <td valign=top>NEW</td>
 <td valign=top>TAPE, SCOTCH, NO.33</td>
 <td valign=top>3.2</td>
 <td>&nbsp;<BR>270.0</td>
 <td>&nbsp;<BR>KK1-43</td>
 <td>&nbsp;<BR>20101008</td>
 <td valign=top>1.0</td>
 <td valign=top>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you want to parse the html yourself, or do you just want to see the table border and cell borders?

Comment: "I want to print the pages exactly as HTML pages displayedI want to print the pages exactly as HTML pages displayed" <-- that's a tough call, since no two browsers display the same HTML page exactly the same :p

Comment: Not necessary to parse the html. I want to printer out the table border and cell borders. What is the easiest implementation to print out the table borders?

Comment: Use CSS, is the simplest way: http://www.elated.com/articles/styling-tables-with-css/

Comment: I need to print the html page out through printer, printing need to display table borders.